# Android Fragment methods not called?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 2 child fragments in my fragment and these fragments have 2 child fragments;

[SearchFragment](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/001d1806b16f57fb713a)

`contentFragment` and its subfragments works perfectly! But when I click on `SearchView` `replaceFragment(searchFragment)` called, but `searchFragment`'s subfragments' methods (onCreate, onCreateView, onViewCreated) not called.

When I close `SearchView`, `searchFragment(contentFragment)` called but contentFragment isn't replaced :/

Ps: I realized while I'm writing this, after I call second `replaceFragment` method, none of subfragment' methods not called. [Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bStRl_Sxq7E&feature=youtu.be)

Is there any problem with `ChildFragmentManager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I find it.

When I create `TabFragment`, I give parent fragment's `childFragmentManager`, and `ViewPager` screws up.

I create a HolderFragmentAdapter and I pass it to TabFragment.

Solved!!

[HolderFragmentAdapter](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/156edc79e64b5308f5c5)